# When do you use "you don't say"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

**you don't say**

My doubt is whether you use this for *exclamations* or for *agreements*, all the references pointed out for saying it when one is  surprised but I am sure I have heard some one say this in an *agreeing* way

> *I failed in my maths exam*
>
> *You don't say!*
>
> ---
>
> *The weather is nice today*
>
> *You don't say*

Comment: Reminds me of an old Spike Jones routine: the phone rings; Spike answers it, and in an increasingly-excited voice he says "You don't say. You *don't* say. You don't say!"  He hangs up, and the audience asks "Who was it?"  "He didn't say."

Comment: And you usually *fail a test.*

Comment: @Noah The first one is for surprised, second one for casual agreement.

Comment: @rps: I don't see how one is a surprise and the other is a casual agreement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is down to intonation.

> "They play horribly"  "you don't say". - disillusioned and agreeing

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you_don%27t_say):

> - They're going to have a baby? You don't say! - surprised
> - "Hey, guess what? There's a country called Brazil!" "You don't say." - sarcastic - the statement is obvious to the person uttering the expression.

Comment: Yes - as in "it's so obvious, you do not need to mention it"

Answer (score 1):

You don't say is a response that can be used, when someone states something that is insanely obvious, and you cannot think of any other legitimate response to say.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they are sarcastically agreeing, as in,

> A:"It is 100 degrees today and I find it is hot." B: "You don't say?"

This is agreeing but it is also being sarcastic.

Another way is to confirm and encourage the person to keep on speaking, as a sort of feedback, but not necessarily as a question, as in "Keep on speaking" or "this is interesting to me".